# DSolve results not what expected

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I have the following formula:

```
s'[t] == 230.94 Tan[0.914743 - 0.138564 t]
```

When I solve this by hand I get:

```
s[t] == 1666.67*Log[Cos[0.914743-0.138564t]] + c
```

But Mathematica just returns:

```
DSolve[s'[t] == 230.94 Tan[0.914743 - 0.138564 t], s[t], t]
```

> s[t] == Integral[ 230.94 Tan[ 0.914743 - 0.138564t ]dt ] + c

Do you know why it isn't solving the integral?

Comment: What's worse, when you make the numbers rational (e.g., 914743/1000000 instead of the constant term in the Tan), Mathematica just hangs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DSolve[s'[t] == (a Tan[b - c t]), s[t], t] /. {a -> 230.94, b -> 0.914743, c -> 0.138564`}

(* {{s[t] -> C[1] + 1666.67 Log[Cos[0.914743 - 0.138564 t]]}} *)
```

Comment: this is a good work around, but the OP is certainly seeing a bug...

Comment: you should read my comment to the OP.